# sed replace text matching complicated regex pattern

Tags: regex, bash, postgresql, sed

I am in the process of porting an existing database schema to Postgresql.

I need to replace occurrences of the word **'go'** with a semi comma.

I have noticed that the word 'go' appears in the text, in the following pattern:

- [non empty string (SQL)]
- [followed by one or more new lines]
- [followed by one or more white space]
- [followed by the word 'go']
- [Followed by one or more new lines]

I want to replace the above pattern with the following one:

- [non empty string (SQL)]
- [followed by ';']
- [Followed by TWO new lines]

I am trying to build a regex expression which I can use with sed, to perform the replacement described above - but I am relatively new to regex.

For the purpose of clarity, I have included sample text BEFORE and AFTER the substitution I want to achieve:

```
-- Original File contents below -------



go
CREATE TABLE foobar
(
    f1    INT,
    f2    INT,
    f3    FLOAT,
        f4    VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    f5    INT,
    f6    datetime,
        f7    smallint
)


go

GRANT UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, SELECT ON foobar TO dbusr
go
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_foobar ON foobar (f1, f2)

go


--- REPLACED FILE CONTENTS -----------



go
CREATE TABLE foobar
(
    f1    INT,
    f2    INT,
    f3    FLOAT,
        f4    VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    f5    INT,
    f6    datetime,
        f7    smallint
);

GRANT UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, SELECT ON foobar TO dbusr;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_foobar ON foobar (f1, f2);
```

Can anyone help with the expression to use to achieve this, so I can execute:
 `sed -i 's/original_match_expr/replacement_expr/g' myfile.sql`

Comment: FWIW, Simply replacing the word 'go' with ';' will result in valid SQL statements, as newlines and spaces are generally irrelevant when running scripts against a Postgresql db (eg. "psql -d <yourdb> -U <youruser> -f <yourscript>")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk)

```
awk -v RS='\\s*go' '{print $0""(RT ~ /go/? ";\n\n": "")}' file.txt
```

The record separator `RS` is set to 0 or more space characters followed by `go`. GNU awk then treats the block of text between two successive instances of record separators as a record. So print the record followed by a custom record separator (`;` followed by two newlines)

Comment: +1 for the one liner - but I have never used awk before, could you please explain what' going on in the expression?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli, added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try following solution using the `GNU` version of [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -ne ':a; $! { N; ba }; s/\([^[:space:]]\)[[:space:]]*go/\1;/g; p' infile
```

It reads the whole file to a buffer and replace all `go` words and all blanks that precede it with a semicolon. It yields:

```
go
CREATE TABLE foobar
(
    f1    INT,
    f2    INT,
    f3    FLOAT,
        f4    VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    f5    INT,
    f6    datetime,
        f7    smallint
);

GRANT UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, SELECT ON foobar TO dbusr;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxu_foobar ON foobar (f1, f2);
```

---

**EDIT** to add an explanation (see comments):

It's not as hard as it seems.

`:a; $! { N; ba }` is a loop that reads every line of input to a buffer.

`[[:space:]]` matches any whitespace character and `[^[:space:]]` negates it. So the substitution command replaces from last non-whitespace character until the word `go`. If there is only whitespace before the `go` word as in the first case, the substitution doesn't match and does replace nothing.

Comment: +1 for the one liner - however, the expression looks very fearsome (even though it worked perfectly on my files) - I don't understand how it works. Could you please explain how the expressions work, so I can learn from your example?.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: Updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll take the time to read it to understand it. Your answer is just as good as 1_CR's, but I'll go with his, since he answered first, and his solution uses sed. Thanks for your help though, much appreciated.